Ubuntu gnome-remote-desktop.service stops working after a while
I have the latest version of Ubuntu at the moment 24.04.1 LTS with gnome remote desktop. When booting the computer, I can log into the remote desktop, this can be done several times in a row and the connection behaves stably. But if some time passes, an error occurs connecting to the gnome desktop, without any description of the error on the client side. Restarting the service does not solve the problem and you have to completely reboot the computer. This situation was there from the very beginning and installing the latest updates did not change anything. I look at the logs like this
journalctl -f -u gnome-remote-desktop.service

But I don't find anything useful for myself. I tried to search for errors from logs, but I found old bugs that were promised to be fixed 2-3 years ago and I think the fixes have already been made.
Does anyone have any ideas on how to solve this problem or in what direction to look?
some logs:
сен 02 21:47:11 john-vServer gnome-remote-de[1102]: [RDP] Network or intentional disconnect, stopping session
сен 02 21:47:37 john-vServer gnome-remote-desktop-daemon[1102]: [21:47:37:201] [1102:00037b09] [ERROR][com.freerdp.core.peer] - [peer_recv_callback_internal]: CONNECTION_STATE_NEGO - rdp_server_accept_nego() fail
сен 02 21:47:37 john-vServer gnome-remote-desktop-daemon[1102]: [21:47:37:201] [1102:00037b09] [ERROR][com.freerdp.core.transport] - [transport_check_fds]: transport_check_fds: transport->ReceiveCallback() - STATE_RUN_FAILED [-1]
сен 02 21:47:37 john-vServer gnome-remote-de[1102]: [RDP] Network or intentional disconnect, stopping session
сен 02 21:47:39 john-vServer gnome-remote-desktop-daemon[1102]: [21:47:39:937] [1102:00037b25] [ERROR][com.freerdp.core.peer] - [peer_recv_callback_internal]: CONNECTION_STATE_NEGO - rdp_server_accept_nego() fail
сен 02 21:47:39 john-vServer gnome-remote-desktop-daemon[1102]: [21:47:39:937] [1102:00037b25] [ERROR][com.freerdp.core.transport] - [transport_check_fds]: transport_check_fds: transport->ReceiveCallback() - STATE_RUN_FAILED [-1]
сен 02 21:47:39 john-vServer gnome-remote-de[1102]: [RDP] Network or intentional disconnect, stopping session
сен 02 21:47:39 john-vServer gnome-remote-desktop-daemon[1102]: [21:47:39:221] [1102:00037b2b] [ERROR][com.freerdp.core.peer] - [peer_recv_callback_internal]: CONNECTION_STATE_NEGO - rdp_server_accept_nego() fail
сен 02 21:47:39 john-vServer gnome-remote-desktop-daemon[1102]: [21:47:39:221] [1102:00037b2b] [ERROR][com.freerdp.core.transport] - [transport_check_fds]: transport_check_fds: transport->ReceiveCallback() - STATE_RUN_FAILED [-1]
сен 02 21:47:39 john-vServer gnome-remote-de[1102]: [RDP] Network or intentional disconnect, stopping session

